# Where to check the deployement

Tags: force.com, deployment

I have moved a custom object from one Developer Edition to other DE using Force.com IDE. Where can I check this deployment's status?

Can anyone tell how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup > Monitor > Deployments

Will show you the deployments in the last 24 hours, no of components and any errors

If your deployment has been successful (the IDE deployment gives you the status at the end), you can find your Custom Object in the same path as it was in the source org, i.e.

Setup > Create > Objects

on the destination org.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. It's working,it's showing the destination org, but i am trying to insert the records into that object in the destination org. How can i do this. Kindly reply me.

Comment: Use DataLoader to insert records. Or to create manually, create a Tab for the Custom Object and you can navigate to the Tab to create a new record.